# Get hostname which has /en/ by JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex, hostname

I would like to create an action only if the url has subfolder `/en/` or `/ar/` for example `http://www.domainname.com/en/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No regex needed! Use indexOf.

From a browser console:

```
var url = "http://www.domainname.com/en/"
undefined

url.indexOf("/en/")
25

url.indexOf("/en/") != -1
true
```

Then your code can be:

```
if (url.indexOf("/en/") != -1) {
    // action here...
}
```

MDN docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf